# Form button refusing to execute javascript divide function

Tags: javascript, html, button, calculation, divide

I am trying to attempt the following exercise from *SAMS Teach Yourself Learn JavaScript in 21 Days*;

"Look at Listing 7.1 and adapt it so that instead of using prompt boxes, the numbers
are entered using an XHTML form."

Listing 7.1 is as follows;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Precision of numbers</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function Calculate(){
var n = 10.0 / 3.0;
document.write("10.0 divided by 3.0 is " + n); 
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Calculate()">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my attempt, but I am just going to put the JS script and form snippet;

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function SetFocus(){
document.Precision.FirstInput.focus();
}
function Calculate(){
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('FirstInput').value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('SecondInput').value); 
if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2){
alert("You made an invalid entry. Please start again.");
document.SimpleForm.reset();
SetFocus();
}
else{
var result document.getElementById('result').value = num1 / num2;
}
}
-->
</script>
```

And the html form

```
<form name="Precision">
<p>
<strong>Enter first number:</strong>
<input type="text" name="FirstInput" id="FirstInput" />
</p>
<p>
<strong>Enter second number:</strong>
<input type="text" name="SecondInput" id="SecondInput" />
</p>
<p>
<strong>The answer is:</strong>
<input type="text" name="result" id="result" />
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="Calculate()">Click here to calculate</button>
</p>
</form>
```

My problem is the button is not executing the function and I would like to know why.

Comment: check console error in devtool->console and change button type to <button type="button">

Comment: If this is really how your chosen Javascript reference/course is teaching you to code, do yourself a favour and get yourself something more up to date. There is so much in here that was maybe commonplace 20 years ago but is bad practice or just looks plain weird now. (Inline event handlers, use of `document.write`, and `document.<form_name>` to reference a form element, use of `var` rather than `let` or `const`, and the weird HTML comments inside the <script> tags.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your code and added some comments for more explanation!

```js
function SetFocus() {
    document.Precision.FirstInput.focus();
}
function Calculate() {
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("FirstInput").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("SecondInput").value);
    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    // add closed parenthesis
    alert("You made an invalid entry. Please start again.");
    document.Precision.reset(); // target Precision form not SimpleForm!?
    SetFocus();
    } else {
    document.getElementById("result").value = num1 / num2;
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="SetFocus()">
<!-- when the page load set focus to first input -->
<form name="Precision">
    <p>
    <strong>Enter first number:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="FirstInput" id="FirstInput" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <strong>Enter second number:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="SecondInput" id="SecondInput" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <strong>The answer is:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="result" id="result" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <button onclick="Calculate()" type="button">
        <!-- add type="button" to prevent form a page from reload -->
        Click here to calculate
    </button>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
```

***Side Notes:***

- The `<!-- -->` is an HTML comment tag.
- Javascript multiline comments, start with a forward slash followed by an asterisk (`/*`) and end with an asterisk followed by a forward slash (`*/`).

Inside `script` tag you write `JS` not `HTML`,So you would use `(/**/)` for commenting not one used by `HTML` (`<!-- -->`).

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I was very stuck with it for days